# Laravel 5.6 - Mixture of POST and AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

## Question

How do I properly output "number:4" to "4" in a Laravel blade when returning angularjs data from `old()`?

## Scenario

I'm posting an object using Laravel routing

```html
<form method="POST" action="/pricestructures/create">

  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="POST">

  {{ csrf_field() }}

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required value="{{old('name')}}" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Client</label>
    <select name="client_id" ng-model="data.client_id" ng-options="o.id as o.name for o in Clients" class="form-control" required ng-change="GetAssets()">
      <option value="">Please select</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Asset</label>
    <select name="asset_id" ng-model="data.asset_id" ng-options="o.id as o.name for o in Assets" class="form-control" required ng-disabled="!data.client_id">
      <option value="">Please select</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Quantity</label>
    <input type="number" name="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" required min="0" step="1" value="{{old('quantity')}}" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Price</label>
    <input type="number" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Price" required min="0" step="0.01" value="{{old('price')}}" required>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

This form is within an AngularJS 1.6 controller and I monitor the client_id select and download relevant assets when it changes using `GetAssets()`. Because I am using AngularJS for this, I am storing the values of both the client_id and asset_id fields in the $scope.

Likewise when any errors are returned I would like to use `old()` to repopulate the $scope variables.

```javascript
$scope.data = {
    client_id: {{ old('client_id',0) }},
    asset_id: {{ old('asset_id',0)}}
};
```

When I submit the form, I can see that the data being sent is being "typed", well, the values associated with the select dropdowns are anyway

[image: FormData]

As mentioned if there is an issue on submitting I repopulate the form with the submitted data using `old()`, however for the `client_id` and `asset_id` variable (i.e. the Angular JS ones) I am being returned "number:1" and I'm not sure how I turn that into "1".

If I happen to store the angularjs variables as strings they get posted as e.g. "string:1"

Comment: Have you considered using the explode function in php to split the string using “:” as the delimiter. Then return the correct thing to blade. This should be done on the php controller

Comment: Hi Toby, yes I have considered it, but I figure it's probably not the "right" way of dealing with this. The "typing" is clearly intentional so I figure there's a way of decoding it (similar to json_decode) however I'm not sure what type of encoding this is.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller try

```
$scope.data = {
    client_id: '{{ old('client_id',0) }}',
    asset_id: '{{ old('asset_id',0)}}'
};
```

just set double quote or single quote and the real value will appear.